# How much data can MySQL hold before having issues?

Tags: mysql, database

This is a bit of a general question but, I recently started paying for a webhost for [my website](https://peq42.com/) and, once I noticed that the MySQL servers are shared(checked phpmyadmin, it has sent 9GB of data on a total of 15k requests the past hour alone, and has been running for 39 days without a restart) and I only have admin control over my own databases, I started wondering:

How big can a MySQL database become before having issues?(Say, long delays, errors, crashes, etc?) Does anyone have experience with that?
Mind you mine runs on MySQL 5.7

Comment: There's no simple answer to this. It depends on the processor and disk speeds, how much memory the server has, how the data is indexed, etc.

Comment: no possible estimation?

Comment: No, this is extremely context dependent. It also depends on the complexity of the queries.

Comment: please note that mysql 5.7 is nearing end of life and soon will no longer receive security updates.  if a hosting provider is only offering 5.7, consider that a big red flag.

Comment: yea but sadly I've no control over what version is used... There is an expected maintenance coming to my host for this next friday, but I can only hope they'll update it

Comment: Their VPS offers have intel Xeon E5-2630 V4 for CPU and "SSDs Intel" for storage, so I'd image thats what they got for web hosting, except shared.

Comment: But you do have control over what hosting provider you use.

Comment: Does your hosting provider offer DEDICATED hosting?  Do you have access to CPANEL with your host?  What is the URL for your hosting provider?

Comment: My host provides the option for dedicated MYSQL and whatnot, but costs more. And yes, I've a CPanel. Its a brazilian host called locaweb

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.  
View profile for contact info.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @peq42 To find out how much sharing is going on with your host, from your browser, myip.ms will take you to a utility site that will ask for your application URL and in less than one minute will report on how many 'live' sites you are sharing on your Shared CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The load you describe should be easy for MySQL on a reasonably powerful server. But it depends on what the queries are, and how well you have optimized.

At my last DBA job, we "gently encouraged" the developers (i.e. alerted them with PagerDuty) if the database size grew over 1TB, or if a single table grew over 512GB, or the queries per second rose over 50k. That's when things started to go south for a typical application workload, if the database and queries were not designed by developers who were especially mindful about optimization. Also the servers were pretty powerful hardware, circa 2020 (48 core Xeon, 256GB RAM, 3TB NVMe storage typically with 2 or 3 physical devices in a RAID).

With more care, it's possible to increase the scale of MySQL a lot higher. With variants like PlanetScale, it can support even more. Cf. https://planetscale.com/blog/one-million-queries-per-second-with-mysql

On the other hand, I saw a photo of one of our NVMe drive literally melted from serving 6k writes per second on a database with half a TB of data. It depends on the types of queries (perhaps it was a faulty NVMe drive).

The only answer that could be useful to you is:

**You must load-test *your* queries on *your* server.**

Also, besides query performance (the only thing most developers care about), you also have to consider database operations. I supported some databases that grew without bound, despite my team's urging the developers to split them up. The result was it would take more than 24 hours to make a backup, which is a problem if there's a policy requirement that backups must be made daily. Also if they wanted to alter a table (e.g. add a column), it could take up to 4 weeks to run.